Filebeat stopped working after changes in the log format
I had a filebeat version 8.7.0 working fine for a long time and sending data to Elastic 8.7.0. It is sending Apache http logs. Originally log looked like this
192.168.10.10 192.168.11.11 - [28/May/2024:16:22:22 +0200] - "GET /request/url HTTP/1.1" 200 64
"-" between timestamp and "GET /request/url..." was a result of misconfiguration. It supposed to be time taken to process request, but it did not work and "-" appeared there instead of time.
At some point this was identified and fixed and log becomes like this ("-" was replaced with the number)
192.168.10.10 192.168.11.11 - [30/May/2024:16:22:22 +0200] 1234 "GET /request/url HTTP/1.1" 200 64
and filebeat stopped working after this change.
Error message in the filebeat logs is this
object mapping for [error] tried to parse field [error] as object, but found a concrete value
So, I read that it is probably due to change of the log format (number instead of "-"), but I could not find how to fix it.
I do not have any custom templates or complex field mapping configuration. I think most of the configuration is default/automatic.
Can anyone help me with fixing this problem?
